# Allow HTML table to be as wide as it can

Tags: jquery, html, css, typescript

I'm creating a `<table>` and it's container (`<div>`). Idea is that table is "relaxed", takes as much space as it needs, and the container would be the "window" for that table, that would have it's `max-width` and `max-height` already set, so it shows scroll bars if and where  its needed (bonus points if I get to set `max-width` for column headers (`<th>`)).

**How I am currently approaching this problem:**
When the table loads, I need the table to stretch as much as it needs, so I can get it's, and it's columns widths with jQuery, so I set the `<div>` `display: fixed;` and get them widths, and then set inline style widths of table and column headers. This isn't working because **table stops stretching when it gets to window width**. If this approach is to work, I'd need the table to be able to stretch beyond window. Other than that, this approach seems to work. **Note** there are much more parent `<div>` elements, but for the sake of simplicity, I'll show only what is closest to the problem. Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="divResultTable" style="display:none">
    <span class="spanResultTableHeader"></span>
    <br />
    <div class="divOuterTableContainer"> <- this is the mentioned container
        <table>                          <- this is the mentioned table
            <thead><tr></tr></thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.divResultTable {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

    .divResultTable span {
        font-size: 18px;
        display: contents;
    }

    .divResultTable .divOuterTableContainer {
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 300px;
        overflow: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }

        .divResultTable .divOuterTableContainer table {
            position: relative;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            table-layout: fixed;
            top: 0;
        }

            .divResultTable .divOuterTableContainer table tr {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }

            .divResultTable .divOuterTableContainer table thead tr th {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                padding: 0px 5px;
                position: sticky;
                top: -1px;
                background-color: #B0B0B0;
            }

            .divResultTable .divOuterTableContainer table tbody tr td {
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                padding: 0px 5px;
                font-size: 12px;
                text-align: left;
            }

            .divResultTable .divOuterTableContainer table tbody tr:nth-child(2n+2) {
                background-color: #E0E0E0;
            }
```

**jQuery in typescript file**

```
// this is executed in a .success function
$("#queryTabBody .divResultTable table").last().css("position", "fixed");
let tableWidth = $("#queryTabBody .divResultTable table").last().width();
var widths: number[] = new Array();
$("#queryTabBody .divResultTable table").last().find("th").each(function (index: number, element: Element) { widths[index] = $(element).width(); });
$("#queryTabBody .divResultTable table").last().find("th").each(function (index: number, element: Element) { $(element).width(widths[index]); });
$("#queryTabBody .divResultTable table").last().width(tableWidth);
$("#queryTabBody .divResultTable table").last().css("position", "");
```

**NOTE** I will not know number of rows or columns of this table. I will not get custom widths for columns from server. I'm just getting name of the table, column names and rows. It's also ok if jQuery takes a second, because I have a "loading overlay", so nothing will be shown until its fully loaded and set to look good. I would like to solve this using CSS and jQuery, without other libraries (job constraints).

**QUESTIONS**
I'm up for a different solution.
I need either a different solution or a way to set the `<table>` to be as wide as it needs in one point in time (before calculating it's and it's column widths), after that, I would set the table back to original position and display.

1. How do I set up my HTML and CSS so that table can overflow window?
2. How do I setup my idea described in the intro?

Comment: What kind of container is your table in? What properties does this container have?

Comment: It's a `div`, and it is well described in the question. Look at HTML and CSS sections.

Comment: Can you make a snippet that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a not-so-recommended solution.
Set the width of the parent element to something extremely large, and then set it back. Here are the edits I made:

```
$("#queryTabBody .divResultTable").last().css("width", "9999999vw"); <- HERE
let tableWidth = $("#queryTabBody .divResultTable table").last().width();
var widths: number[] = new Array();
$("#queryTabBody .divResultTable table").last().find("th").each(function (index: number, element: Element) { widths[index] = $(element).width(); });
$("#queryTabBody .divResultTable table").last().find("th").each(function (index: number, element: Element) { $(element).width(widths[index]); });
$("#queryTabBody .divResultTable table").last().width(tableWidth);
$("#queryTabBody .divResultTable").last().css("width", ""); <- HERE
```

For other juniors like me, when width is set to "some_number vw", the vw stands for view width, the width of your window (seniors, correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 1):

I adivse you to use the jquery [datatable](https://datatables.net/) it's amazing library to control the datatable and they have so many utilities such as scroll utility that i included in my answer.

**Check the snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        '50vh',
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

```html
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sydney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sydney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008/12/11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008/09/26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2012/04/09</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/12/06</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/11/13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: It looks good, but (I admit it's my fault, sorry) I didn't note that I wouldn't use other libraries. I won't say why other than it's related to my job, and as a junior it's really not up to me to add more libraries. I will edit this in my question, and I'm glad you made a good solution for it, because it might help someone else.